# Why result of openssl encrypto is different from result of php openssl_encrypt function?

Tags: php, security, encryption, openssl

## Environment

- PHP7.4
- OpenSSL 3.0.0

## Question

### As shown below, result of openssl encrypto command is different from result of php openssl_encrypt function. Why result of two command isn't same?

`$ php -r 'var_dump(openssl_encrypt("test@email.com", "bf-cbc","a88e2d710bee460c", 0,"11111111"));'`
string(24) "4iZiBW4UYWswVd3fkS+OOA=="

`$ echo "test@email.com" | openssl enc -bf-cbc -K "61383865326437313062656534363063" -iv "3131313131313131" -base64 -A -provider legacy` (if version 1, no need to add -provider legacy)
(output) "4iZiBW4UYWsfLsRE7dKxZQ=="

in hex, KEY "a88e2d710bee460c" equal "6138 3865 3264 3731 3062 6565 3436 3063". (result of `$ printf a88e2d710bee460c | xxd`)
iv "11111111" equal "3131 3131 3131 3131" (result of `$ printf 11111111 | xxd`)

## As for decrypto

`$ echo "4iZiBW4UYWswVd3fkS+OOA==" | openssl enc -d -bf-cbc -K "61383865326437313062656534363063" -iv "3131313131313131" -base64 -provider legacy`
(output with no newline) test@email.com

`$ echo "4iZiBW4UYWsfLsRE7dKxZQ==" | openssl enc -d -bf-cbc -K "61383865326437313062656534363063" -iv "3131313131313131" -base64 -provider legacy`
(output with newline) test@email.com

Answer (score 0):

I have self-resolved the problem.

When we use echo command of unix, there are newline unless　adding option -n.

so, below two command is same result.

`$ php -r 'var_dump(openssl_encrypt("test@email.com", "bf-cbc","a88e2d710bee460c", 0,"11111111"));'`
string(24) "4iZiBW4UYWswVd3fkS+OOA=="

`$ echo -n "test@email.com" | openssl enc -bf-cbc -K "61383865326437313062656534363063" -iv "3131313131313131" -base64 -A -provider legacy`
(output) 4iZiBW4UYWswVd3fkS+OOA==